# Getting key within key firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have **customers** data stored in below format in my `firebase` database.

```
{
  "fEYfwd8p9oSGAF6iUtXDLkMBCqc2" : { //user id
    "-KdLAGG-8VOMd62Noyc8" : { //customer id
      "customerCode" : "shi",
      "customerLimit" : "2569",
      "customerName" : "Shishir"
    },
    "-KdOraGISFJ6epjWucfh" : { //customer id
      //other cust details
    }
  },
  "jxW41BgSNWdRPyWtUkZA2G0eLhf2" : { //user id
    "-KdCgJKh6_Rb8MOi-fIj" : {
      "customerCode" : "Kau",
      "customerLimit" : "800",
      "customerName" : "Kaushik"
    },
    "-KdCgacTYBkThnVWe4sb" : {
      //other cust details
    },
    "-KdCggxld52mq0DsGRjH" : {
      //other cust details
    },
    "-KdChbdoV7nxwZoGLWsY" : {
      //other cust details
    }
  }
}
```

In my android application am trying to check whether customer code exists before creating other details for customers and below is how am doing it.

```
DatabaseReference dbRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customers")
                       .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
dbRef.orderByChild("customerCode").equalTo(code).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
           if (!snapshot.exists()) {
               editTextAC.setText("");
               editTextAC.setError("Customer code not found in database.");
           } else {
               //need to get customer id here.
           }
       }
       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError dbError) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, dbError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
});
```

I am getting data in snapshot in below format.

```
{
    key = jxW41BgSNWasdsaRPsdyaWtUkZA2G0eLhf2,
    value = {-KdChbdoV7nfdasxwZoGLWsY = {
                customerCode = Ses,
                customerLimit = 78888,
                customerName = Sheshu
            }
    }
}
```

I need to get customer Id from above `value`. I tried doing `snapshot.getKey()` which retrieves first level `key` i.e. `jxW41BgSNWasdsaRPsdyaWtUkZA2G0eLhf2` and when I say `snapshot.getValue()` which would retrieve `value` as string. How would I get customer Id from above?

Comment: try `for (String customerId  : snapshot.getValue()) {
    // print customerId
}`. I can do it with iOS but i'm not sure it work with android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
    Log.i("TAG", "child key = " + child.getKey());
}
```

Comment: A small doubt.. Am sure that I will be getting single data everytime as customerCode is unique here.. So do I need to use `for` loop here?

Comment: in your data, i see there are many `customer id` inside a `user id` so you need a for loop

Comment: No.. If you see that code, then am getting customer Code based on the logged in user id.. So for each user id, customer code is unique.. So am pretty sure there will be only one data fetched..

Comment: now I understand your problem but I don't face it before. please try `DataSnapshot child = snapshot.getValue(); String key = child.getKey()`;

Comment: Ok bro.. Seems promising.. Let me try this and let you know.. :)

Comment: I don't think that would work because `snapshot.getValue()` would return `Object` but it requires `DataSnapshot` to be returned.. Anyways.. I would go with for loop itself.. But am still wondering why doesn't it work without loop.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseReference dbRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customers")
                   .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());dbRef.orderByChild("customerCode").equalTo(code).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       if (!snapshot.exists()) {
           editTextAC.setText("");
           editTextAC.setError("Customer code not found in database.");
       } else {
             for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
               Log.e("Customer_id",child.getKey());}
       }
   }
   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError dbError) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, dbError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }});
```